# Java: bring value in [0,1] range

Tags: java, algorithm

If I have a LinkedList of double with positive and negative value, for example:

```
[-1000, 34, 0, -700, 12]
```

How I can do to bring in [0,1] range?

If I have only positive number I can do:

```
(x - Xmin) / (Xmax-Xmin)
```

But with both positive and negative value?

Comment: `Math.abs((x - Xmin) / (Xmax-Xmin))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformation remains the same: `(x - Xmin) / (Xmax-Xmin)`.

If you have negative numbers, subtracting the smallest of these is adding its magnitude to all values.  `Xmin` will end up at zero, anything larger will end up positive.  Then scaling by `(Xmax-Xmin)` brings all values into the [0,1] range.  Try a few cases by hand to see that it's so.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should still work.

`x-Xmin` moves all of your numbers so that they are all positive, with the smallest one equal to zero.

`/(Xmax-Xmin)` Scales the numbers so that the largest one is equal to 1, the smallest one stays at zero, and the ones in the middle are scaled proportionately.

so
`(x-Xmin)/(Xmax-Xmin)` has exactly the effect you want.